# Keep your distance!

Tags: king-of-the-hill

Every player has a number. Can yours be the farthest from them all?

### Requirements

Write a Java, Python 2, or Ruby function named `choose()` that accepts three arguments:

- an integer - the number of rounds already completed
- an integer - the number of players
- an array of strings - the results of each previous round

  - each string is a space-separated list of integers, sorted from lowest to highest

For example, `choose(2, 4, ["4 93 93 174", "1 84 234 555"])` means:

- there were already two rounds (this is the third round)
- there are a total of four players
- in the first round, the numbers chosen were 4, 93, 93, 174
- in the second round, the numbers chosen were 1, 84, 234, 555

You must return a whole number from 1 to 999 (inclusive).

For each other player, your score is the square root of the distance between your number and theirs. Your score for the round is the total of all of these scores.

100 rounds will be played. The highest total score wins!

### Rules

- Your code may not use any I/O, including console, files, network, etc.
- You may not interfere with the control program or any other players.
- Programs which look like they violate the above rules will be excluded.
- Each call of a function should take under five seconds on my computer (Intel Core i5 2450M with 8GB of RAM).
- If a program throws an exception or returns an invalid value, it will be treated as if it returned 1.
- Each user may submit at most one program.

### Miscellaneous

- The control program is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Ypnypn/src).
- There are three built-in players. They can be found in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44782/16294).
- The winner will be chosen on January 28.

### Leaderboard

The winner is [Conservator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44802/16294).

Honorable mention to [Gustav](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45001/16294), the highest scoring player with a non-constant strategy.

- Conservator - 36226
- High - 36115
- FloorHugger - 35880
- NumberOne - 35791
- Overestimator - 35791
- Gustav - 35484
- Historian - 35201
- Sampler - 34960
- Incrementer - 34351
- JumpRightIn - 34074
- Vickrey - 34020
- Teenager - 33907
- Randu - 33891
- Weightlifter - 33682
- Middleman - 33647
- BounceInwards - 33529
- NastyMathematician - 33292
- Jumper - 33244
- Copycat - 33049

The full results can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/W42DHeGd). (I recommend disabling text wrapping.)

Comment: Do I have any way of telling which was my own number in those previous rounds?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the controller, and I have no clue how to get org.python.core and the org.ruby. A quick google search gave me some links to jython. Is the code written in jython or something? Can you give me some links? Thanks.

Comment: @Maltysen It uses the Jython and JRuby jar files. I'll mention this in the GitHub readme.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Wait. I ran the installers but its still not working. Can't find either python or java. BTW the command I'm running is javac *.java since jruby/jython is in my path. Any clue to what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I need the standalone?

Comment: I don't know any of those languages :( Could you add JavaScript? Like, run it with node.js?

Comment: @TheWobbuffet, I don't know any of them either.  Didn't stop me from making a Python entry.

Comment: @Mark Sometimes I want to start learning a new language, but then I remind myself I'm not even intermediate in any of the languages I do know. I would be able to do this because I know the basic syntax of python, but I don't know anything about return statements and I'm too lazy to search the doc... yeah... there's also the fact that I don't know which version of python I want to learn.

Comment: @Maltysen I'm not sure. (I used NetBeans to write, compile, and run everything.) If the Java can't be found, check to make sure the folders are correct - all players should be in KotH/src/Players/ , and the code in KotH/src/koth/ . What are the exact error messages you're facing?

Comment: It gives me "PythonPlayer.java:4: error: package org.python.core does not exist" for all of them and the ruby equivelant. I'm using javac -cp jruby.jar:jythonn.jar *.java

Comment: Wow. Based on the current leaderboard it looks like it's just best to pick 1 or 999 all the time.

Comment: Holy moly, I thought it was not a bad choice, but wow :)

Comment: I think it would have been more interesting if the space was a circle/loop so that the distance between 1 and 999 is 1. That would keep the "guess a single number every turn" from dominating, since there aren't "edges" to park on. Obviously too late to change now though ;)

Comment: @Geobits, perhaps "Keep your distance on a circle" could be a separate question. The results would be much more interesting.

Comment: @CarpetPython Someone should ask that. I thought it seemed pretty obvious that picking 1 or 999 every time would be the best strategy.

Comment: @CarpetPython Mind if I post that challenge?

Comment: @KSFT, please do. If the "duplicate police" don't get you, I will be posting an answer for sure.

Comment: @CarpetPython Why? Is it a duplicate of something else, or do you just mean this?

Comment: I meant this. Some people may say the "circle" variant to too much like this challenge. You may have to describe how the circular aspect makes it a different puzzle needing different answers. I don't much like the duplicate rules here (as long as credit is given to earlier work), but we have inherited them from the Q&A format where it is a very good rule.

Comment: @CarpetPython I just started writing the question when I realized that I don't have a controller. I don't know Java very well, so I guess I'll just write a new one in Python. Is it just supposed to take the names of files containing two programs as input and output the winner?

Comment: @KSFT I think you only need to change line 45 of Contest.java

Comment: @CarpetPython/kaine/anyone else  I'm about to post it. Am I supposed to run the control program to determine scores? Should I run it with every pair of programs? Also, I can't figure out how to compile the control program.

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to compile the control program, but I'm still not sure what I'm supposed to do and what people who write submissions are supposed to do.

Comment: I posted it here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45216/keep-your-distance-on-a-circle

Comment: I can't get the control program to work. Do the Java submissions need to be surrounded with class declarations?

Comment: @KSFT Yes. Use `package Players; class ProgramName {public static int choose(int ...`

Comment: Why only Python 2? Is there something wrong with Python 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Python, Conservator

```py
def choose(round, players, scores):
    return 999
```

Since every exception throws 1, it stays away as much as possible from it. Makes its fortune at the expense of the weak.

Fun fact: I thought about improving it, but couldn't find a better way than just hiding in a corner.

Comment: Looks like I picked the wrong corner.   :(

Comment: It is good for a simple reason: Others try to minimize the distance to you. They will automatically make your score better. A game changer would be an opponent who trys to get as close to you as possible.

Comment: Eww...a semicolon in Python?

Comment: @KSFT hehe I'm rusty on Python, and I've never been that expert anyway

Answer (score 6):

## Number One, Java

The name explains this one completely.

```java
public static int choose(int round, int players, String[] args) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I especially like how the user name ties into the submission

Answer (score 5):

## Python, AncientHistorian

Firmly believes that the future will be exactly like the past, but believes the last round is too recent to be histiry, so it just loops through 1 - 999 and chooses what would have been the best the previous rounds exept the last. First 2 round returns 500.

```
def choose(round, players, scores):
    calc = lambda n, scores: sum([abs(int(i)-n)**.5 for i in scores.split(' ')])
    return max(range(1, 1000), key=lambda n: sum([calc(n, j) for j in scores[1:]])) if round>1 else 500
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python, Vickrey

```py
def choose(rounds, players, results):        
    if not results:
        return (id(0)/7)%999 + 1

    def best(array):
        score = lambda x: sum(abs(x-y)**.5 for y in array)
        m = max(score(x) for x in range(1, 1000))
        return [x for x in range(1, 1000) if score(x) == m]

    def second_best(array):
        array.extend(best(array))
        options = best(array)
        return options[(id(0)/7) % len(options)]

    results = [map(int, s.split()) for s in results]
    counts = {}

    for round_ in results:
        for number in round_:
            counts[number] = counts.get(number, 0) + 1

    most_common = sorted([(c, n) for n,c in counts.items()], reverse=True)
    to_avoid = [t[1] for t in most_common[:players]]
    
    return second_best(to_avoid)
```

Makes a list of numbers which have been played often, assumes that everyone else will play optimally and opts for the *second* best choice given the list.

For example, if the most common numbers are `[1, 990, 999]`, then Vickrey inserts the optimal play 200 to give `[1, 200, 990, 999]`, then picks the best option for the new array (which is 556).

Answer (score 4):

### Java, Overestimator

As the name suggests, this program assumes all the other programs will try to play "well" by picking the best answer based on the last round - so this "overestimator" always picks the **worst** possible position based on the previous round.

```
 public static int choose(int round, int players, String[] args) {
     String[] lastRoundStrings = args[args.length - 1].split(" ");
     int[] lastRound = new int[lastRoundStrings.length];
     int worstSelection = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < lastRound.length; i++) {
         double worstScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
         for (int j = 1; j < 999; j++) {
             double computedScore = score(j, lastRound);
             if (computedScore < worstScore) {
                 worstScore = computedScore;
                 worstSelection = j;
             }
         }
     }
     return worstSelection;
 }

 public static double score(int position, int[] otherPositions) {
     double total = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < otherPositions.length; i++) {
         total += Math.sqrt(Math.abs(otherPositions[i] - position));
     }
     return total;
 }
```

Comment: How come this played a constant "1"? Was there a bug? Mind you, playing "1" proved to be quite successful. :)

Comment: Sadly the code has a bug, yes - it never actually parses the scores it reads from the last round. (But I realised it too late and it seemed wrong to edit a submission by then, plus as you say it was doing pretty well so... whatever :p)

Answer (score 4):

## Java - Weightlifter

Loops through 1-999 to figure out which would be the best for each round. Weighs them according to recency (recent rounds have more weight), and returns its best overall guess. Hopefully if patterns form in later round, this will be able to pick up on it.

**Edit: Now with +Inf% more recursion!**
Not being able to store/save/see what you chose on previous rounds is a drag. Taking your own inputs into account messes you up when trying to figure out what *others* are going to do. So, let's compute it! This will now recurse to figure out what it chose on the previous round and ignore that when calculating the next move.

Note that it only *really* ignores its own input from the last turn, but since that one is weighted the highest, it seems to work okay. This could be fixed with a bit more work, but I'll wait for the leaderboard to see if it's needed.

```java
int choose(int rounds, int players, String[] hist){
    if(rounds < 1)
        return 1;
    
    int lastChoice = choose(rounds-1,players,java.util.Arrays.copyOf(hist, hist.length-1));
    
    int[][] history = new int[hist.length][players];
    for(int i=0;i<hist.length;i++){
        String[] tokens = hist[i].split(" ");
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int j=0;j<tokens.length;j++){
            history[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
            if(i==history.length-1 && history[i][j]==lastChoice && !flag){
                flag = true;
                history[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    double best = 0;
    int guess = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
        double score = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<history.length;j++){
            double weight = (double)(j+1)/history.length;
            for(int k=0;k<history[j].length;k++){
                if(history[j][k] > 0)
                    score += Math.sqrt(Math.abs(history[j][k]-i)) * weight;
            }
        }
        if(score > best){
            best = score;
            guess = i;
        }
    }
    return guess;
}
```

Comment: Note: Even at round 100, it completes in under a second on my somewhat-slow PC. If it takes too long on yours for some reason, let me know so I can limit the recursion.

Comment: It's very fast on my machine as well.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, JumpRightIn

```
def choose(round, players, args)
    return 500 if args.size == 0
    last_round = args[-1].split.map(&:to_i) + [1000]
    max_gap = 0
    last = 0
    move = 1
    last_round.each { |i|
        gap = i - last - 1
        if gap > max_gap
            max_gap = gap
            move = (i + last)/2
        end
        last = i
    }
    move
end
```

It's probably the most straight-forward strategy. It finds the largest gap in the last round, and chooses the number right in the middle of that gap.

Comment: What does it return for the first round? 1?

Comment: @mbomb007 Oh, I always forget these pesky initial rounds. Thanks, it now returns 500.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, Copycat

Simply returns whichever number won last time.

```
def choose r, p, hist
  last = hist.last.split.map &:to_i
  scores = last.map{|n| last.map{|m| (n-m).abs ** 0.5 }.inject :+ }
  last[scores.index scores.max]
end
```

Comment: What does it return for the first round? Oh never mind. Exceptions would return 1.

Answer (score 3):

## Gustav (Python 2)

This is a pretty straight forward meta strategy, shamelessly copied from one of my old [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35006/29703) in a similar KotH challenge. It considers a few simple strategies, looks how they would have performed over all previous rounds, and then follows the highest scoring one for the next round.

```python
def choose(k, N, h):
    if k<2: return 999
    H = [[int(x) for x in l.split()] for l in h]
    score = lambda x,l: sum(abs(x-y)**.5 for y in l)
    S = [range(1,1000)
         + [max(range(1,1000), key=lambda x: score(x, H[i-1]))]
         + [max(range(1,1000), key=lambda x: score(x, H[i-2]))]
         + [min(range(1,1000), key=lambda x: score(x, H[i-1]))]
         + [min(range(1,1000), key=lambda x: score(x, H[i-2]))]
         for i in range(2,k+1)]
    scores = [sum(score(s[j],l) for s,l in zip(S[:-1], H[2:]))
              for j in range(len(S[0]))]
    return max(zip(scores, S[-1]))[1]
```

I realize now that the algorithm still has some flaws. E.g. it might keep "chasing itself" because it does not distinguish its own moves from those of the opponents. However, I'll leave it like this for now.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, Randu

Numbers selected by [the most ill-conceived random number generator ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU).

```
def choose(round, players, scores):
    x = 15
    for i in range(round * players + 1):
        x = (x * 65539) % 2147483648
    y = int((x / 2147483648.0) * 999.0)+1
    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

The following three programs are built-in.

### High (Ruby)

```
def choose(round, players, args)
    return 990
end
```

### Incrementer (Java)

```
public static int choose(int round, int players, String[] args) {
    return round * 10 + 5;
}
```

### FloorHugger (Python)

```
def choose(round, players, args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return 10
    last = args[-1].split();

# next line from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7368801/3148067
    last = map(int, last)

    dist = 0
    for i in range(1, 999):
        if i in last:
            dist = 0
        else:
            dist = dist + 1
            if dist == 10:
                return i
    return 500
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, Sampler

Out of a list of places, choose the one that is farthest away from recently used
numbers, ignoring the previous turn.

```
def choose(turn, players, history):
    sample = map(int, (' '.join( history[-5:-1] )).split())
    def distance(x): return sum(abs(x-y)**0.5 for y in sample)
    places = range(1, 1000, 13)
    score, place = max((distance(x), x) for x in places)
    return place
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java, BounceInwards

Starting at 1, it gradually gets closer to 500 while bouncing between the higher and lower option.

```
public static int choose(int round, int players, String[] args) {
    return round%2 == 0 ? round * 5 : 1000 - round * 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### NastyMathematician (Java)

Examines the last two rounds (if the best numbers were 70 and 80, it will output 90). It is nasty because it tries to take as high numbers as possible to win against his opponents.

```
public static int choose(int round, int players, String[] args) {
    if (round == 0) {
        return 999;
    }

    int[][] results = new int[args.length][players];

    // parse input
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        String[] rounds = args[i].split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < rounds.length; j++) {
            results[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(rounds[j]);
        }
    }

    int bestNumber = 0;
    double bestScore = -1;

    // get the best number for the last round
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        double score = 0;
        for (int result : results[results.length - 1]) {
            score += Math.sqrt(Math.abs(i - result));
        }
        if (score >= bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            bestNumber = i;
        }
    }

    if (round == 1) {
        return bestNumber;
    }

    int bestNumber2 = 0;
    double bestScore2 = -1;

    // get the best number for the second last round
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        double score = 0;
        for (int result : results[results.length - 2]) {
            score += Math.sqrt(Math.abs(i - result));
        }
        if (score > bestScore2) {
            bestScore2 = score;
            bestNumber2 = i;
        }
    }

    // add the difference between last round and second last round to get this rounds best number
    int difference = bestNumber - bestNumber2;
    bestNumber = bestNumber + difference;

    return bestNumber > 999 ? 999 : bestNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - I don't want to think of a name...

If the average of the numbers chosen in the past rounds is less than 500, it picks 999. It picks 1 otherwise.

```
def choose(a,b,c):
    total=0
    for i in c:
        for j in i.split(" "):
            total+=int(i)
    average=total/(a*b)
    if average<500:
        return 999
    return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, Middleman (based on conservator by @clabacchio)

```py
def choose(round, players, scores):
    return 500;
```

After I noticed that the upper edge scores high (and outperformed the lower edge), I wondered whether there could be anything worse than just getting caught in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

## Jumper (Ruby)

```
def choose(round, players, args)
    495*(round%3)+5
end
```

Alternates between bottom, middle and top.
(5,500,995)